# What is sort doing

Tags: shell-script, sort

This is a followup to this question : [What does sort -n do with non numeric values?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165060/what-does-sort-n-do-with-non-numeric-values?noredirect=1#comment271134_165060)

Here is my input:

```
1-----***
R----****
1---*****
```

And I run:

```
sort -k 1.2,1.9n input.txt > output.txt
```

Here is my output:

```
1-----***
1---*****
R----****
```

And my expected output:

```
1---*****
R----****
1-----***
```

I expect this output since the ASCII value of * (42) is smaller than the value of - (45). However, it appears the R is being considered in the sort, but I thought 1.2,1.9 would exclude it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did the answer you were directed to solve your first question? If so, please let me know and I will close it as a dupe.

Comment: Yes, it solved it in that I know there is an ascii comparison going on now, but I'm still not clear on the details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using an invalid key for sort (invalid because it is not matching your input text).  The info manual for sort suggests using the `--debug` option to investigate the behavior of what they key is matching.  Using your command key, `1.2,1.9n`, sort produces the following output:

```
% sort -k 1.2,1.9n --debug input.txt 
sort: using ‘en_US.UTF-8’ sorting rules
1-----***
 ^ no match for key
_________
1---*****
 ^ no match for key
_________
R----****
 ^ no match for key
_________
```

and appears to be falling back on a default sort using the whole field.  If you omit the `n` from your key and just use `1.2,1.9` you instead get the following:

```
% sort -k 1.2,1.9 --debug input.txt 
sort: using ‘en_US.UTF-8’ sorting rules
1-----***
 ________
_________
R----****
 ________
_________
1---*****
 ________
_________
```

which is properly using the 2nd through 9th characters of the first field for the sort operation.

Comment: Nice, didn't know about --debug